# perform lookup on two arrays and add element from second array to first array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two arrays that I have looped over to match an element from the 1st array `vals1` in the second one`vals2`. If the element(index [i][0]) from `vals1` is present in `vals2`(index [j][0]), I need to grad the element (index[j][1]) from `vals2` and push to `vals1` (or create a new array with all elements of `vals1` and the one from `vals2`)If it isn't present, I want to assign 'Unassigned' where I would have used element[j][1] from ```vals2``

```
So:
If vals1 = [[ 'item3', 3, 2, 6 ],[ 'item6', 4, 7, 28 ],[ 'item8', 1, 8, 8 ],[ 'item2', 6, 12, 72 ]]
and vals2 = [[ 'item1', 15 ],[ 'item2', 4 ],[ 'item3', 1 ],[ 'item4', 2 ]] 
I'm looking for the following result:
[[ 'item3', 3, 2, 6,1 ],[ 'item6', 4, 7, 28,'Unassigned' ],[ 'item8', 1, 8, 8,Unassigned' ],[ 'item2', 6, 12, 72,4 ]]
```

The script I have so far is:

```
function lookup () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet11');
  var vals1 = sheet1.getRange(2,1,sheet1.getLastRow(),sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet12');
  var vals2 = sheet2.getRange(2,1,sheet2.getLastRow(),sheet2.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  console.log(vals1);
  [ 
    [ 'item3', 3, 2, 6 ], 
    [ 'item6', 4, 7, 28 ],  
    [ 'item8', 1, 8, 8 ],
    [ 'item2', 6, 12, 72 ],
  ]
  console.log(vals2);
 [ 
  [ 'item1', 15 ],
  [ 'item2', 4 ],
  [ 'item3', 1 ],
  [ 'item4', 2 ]
 ] 

 var result =[]; 

 for(var i=0;i<vals1.length;i++){
   for(var j=0;j<vals2.length;j++){
     var desc = vals1[i][0]
     var qty = vals1[i][1]
     var selling = vals1[i][2]
     var total = vals1[i][3]
     var desc2 = vals2[j][0]
     var cost = vals2[j][1]
     
     
     if(desc === desc2){
       result.push([desc,qty,selling,total,cost]) 
     } else {
       result.push([desc,qty,selling,total,'Unassigned'])
     }

   }
 } 
 console.log(result)
}
```

And the result I'm getting is:

```
[ [ 'item3', 3, 2, 6, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item3', 3, 2, 6, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item3', 3, 2, 6, 1 ],
  [ 'item3', 3, 2, 6, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item3', 3, 2, 6, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item3', 3, 2, 6, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item2', 4, 7, 28, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item2', 4, 7, 28, 4 ],
  [ 'item2', 4, 7, 28, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item2', 4, 7, 28, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item2', 4, 7, 28, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item2', 4, 7, 28, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item4', 1, 8, 8, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item4', 1, 8, 8, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item4', 1, 8, 8, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item4', 1, 8, 8, 2 ],
  [ 'item4', 1, 8, 8, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item4', 1, 8, 8, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item2', 6, 12, 72, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item2', 6, 12, 72, 4 ],
  [ 'item2', 6, 12, 72, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item2', 6, 12, 72, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item2', 6, 12, 72, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item2', 6, 12, 72, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item4', 3, 34, 102, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item4', 3, 34, 102, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item4', 3, 34, 102, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item4', 3, 34, 102, 2 ],
  [ 'item4', 3, 34, 102, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item4', 3, 34, 102, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item3', 2, 8, 16, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item3', 2, 8, 16, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item3', 2, 8, 16, 1 ],
  [ 'item3', 2, 8, 16, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item3', 2, 8, 16, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item3', 2, 8, 16, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item1', 8, 32, 256, 15 ],
  [ 'item1', 8, 32, 256, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item1', 8, 32, 256, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item1', 8, 32, 256, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item1', 8, 32, 256, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item1', 8, 32, 256, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item1', 21, 32, 672, 15 ],
  [ 'item1', 21, 32, 672, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item1', 21, 32, 672, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item1', 21, 32, 672, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item1', 21, 32, 672, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item1', 21, 32, 672, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item2', 2, 7, 14, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item2', 2, 7, 14, 4 ],
  [ 'item2', 2, 7, 14, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item2', 2, 7, 14, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item2', 2, 7, 14, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item2', 2, 7, 14, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item5', 4, 6, 24, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item5', 4, 6, 24, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item5', 4, 6, 24, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item5', 4, 6, 24, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item5', 4, 6, 24, 4 ],
  [ 'item5', 4, 6, 24, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item8', 9, 8, 72, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item8', 9, 8, 72, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item8', 9, 8, 72, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item8', 9, 8, 72, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item8', 9, 8, 72, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item8', 9, 8, 72, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item3', 16, 2, 32, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item3', 16, 2, 32, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item3', 16, 2, 32, 1 ],
  [ 'item3', 16, 2, 32, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item3', 16, 2, 32, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item3', 16, 2, 32, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item7', 32, 6, 192, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item7', 32, 6, 192, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item7', 32, 6, 192, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item7', 32, 6, 192, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item7', 32, 6, 192, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item7', 32, 6, 192, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item6', 1, 21, 21, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item6', 1, 21, 21, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item6', 1, 21, 21, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item6', 1, 21, 21, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item6', 1, 21, 21, 'Unassigned' ],
  [ 'item6', 1, 21, 21, 'Unassigned' ],
```

The data sets im working from has 1701 rows and 228 rows respectivly. When I originally ran the script it printed over 400 000 rows of data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunc( ) {
  let v1 = [[ 'item3', 3, 2, 6 ],[ 'item6', 4, 7, 28 ],[ 'item8', 1, 8, 8 ],[ 'item2', 6, 12, 72 ]];
  let v2 = [[ 'item1', 15 ],[ 'item2', 4 ],[ 'item3', 1 ],[ 'item4', 2 ]]; 
  let v0 =v2.map(r=>{return r[0]});//just getting all of the the first elements of v2 in a flatten array for  use with indexOf
  v1.forEach((r,i)=>{
    let idx=v0.indexOf(r[0]); 
    if(idx>-1) {//if idx is greater than -1 the matches first element v2
      v1[i].push(v2[idx][1]);
    }else{
      v1[i].push('UnAssigned')
    }
  });
  console.log(v1);
}
```

The output was:

```
[ [ 'item3', 3, 2, 6, 1 ],
  [ 'item6', 4, 7, 28, 'UnAssigned' ],
  [ 'item8', 1, 8, 8, 'UnAssigned' ],
  [ 'item2', 6, 12, 72, 4 ] ]
```

Comment: Legend @Cooper. That works exactly as I wanted. Thanks for the help. I have two question  for you if I may? Could you perhaps briefly explain how this works? I'm still pretty new at this. I'm familiar with the .map and .indexOf methods but have only used them with the older syntax's. Thanks again for your help, this is going to save me tons of time.

Comment: My bad. I see your comments in your answer now. I got it. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

- Iterate through all items in the first 2D array (`vals1`). You can do that with [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), for example.
- For each item in `vals1`, you want to look for the same item in `vals2`. You can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for that. Since items are the first element in each inner array, you would have to check whether `item1[0] === item2[0]`.
- If the item is found, [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the corresponding value `item2[1]` to the item's inner array in `vals1`.
- If the item is not found (`find` returns `undefined`), push the string `"Unassigned"` instead.

#### Code snippet:

```
function lookup(vals1, vals2) {
  vals1.forEach(item1 => {
    const item2 = vals2.find(item2 => item1[0] === item2[0]);
    const newValue = item2 ? item2[1] : "Unassigned";
    item1.push(newValue);
  });
  return vals1;
}
```

#### Regular function syntax:

```
function lookup(vals1, vals2) {
  vals1.forEach(function(item1) {
    const item2 = vals2.find(function(item2) {
      return item1[0] === item2[0]
    });
    const newValue = item2 ? item2[1] : "Unassigned";
    item1.push(newValue);
  });
  return vals1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your responce @lamblichus. I'll definitly apply this solution. Will let you know how i got on, but this makes total sence too.

Comment: @lamblichus. So I implemented your lookup method on a separate project I'm working with and it definitely does the job. If I'm honest, I'll probably be using this method going forward purely because I understand it better. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: @lamblichus, would it be possible for you to write the above using the regular function syntax? Im not great at understanding or adapting arrow functions. Id like to use the method you suggested in a separate use case but am struggling  a bit with the arrow function syntax.

Comment: @ChrisWard I'm sorry I missed your last comment. I added a code snippet with classical function syntax, I hope this is helpful.

Comment: No problem at all @lamblichus. Thanks for including the classical syntax snippet, it will definitly help. This lookup methodology has become really handy for me.