# Iterate through a table and then creating multiple rows after queries

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 separate sheets

One called Roster

[image]

Another called tasks

[image]

What I need to do on a third sheet, is iterate over the Roster and for each row, look at the tasks table for a match Department AND Role. and create a new row containing a mix of data from both tables, this however can lead to needing multiple rows from a single row on Roster. The below is a sample of the output I am aiming for
[image]

Could anyone advise how this can be achieved via formula ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google spreadsheet "=QUERY" join() equivalent function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796620/google-spreadsheet-query-join-equivalent-function)

Comment: It does not seem to I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similair need a little while ago. Go check the below link out. There were two answers posted and both work perfectly.  I've adapted the methods to do exactly what you are looking to do many times. Good luck, hope this helps.

P.S Im not actually posting this as an answer. I cant respond to your original question so have just posted it this way.

[perform lookup on two arrays and add element from second array to first array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66109952/perform-lookup-on-two-arrays-and-add-element-from-second-array-to-first-array/66115897?noredirect=1#comment117460289_66115897)

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a formula based solution rather than script